# UCD WAS Config plugin can't find the WAS installation

Tags: udeploy, urbancode

My WAS 8.5 is installed in C:\Program Files(x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\wsadmin.bat. How can I tell the discovery process to look at my installation location?

```
plugin: WAS - Deploy, id: com.urbancode.air.plugin.WebSphere, version: 98
plugin command: 'cmd' '/C' '""C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\opt\groovy-1.8.8\bin\groovy" -cp "C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\plugins\com.urbancode.air.plugin.WebSphere_98_b9f10d322ce14ba5b38aa4757ce3ac59f5ec7643b2b922935ccab03536b404a2\classes;C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\plugins\com.urbancode.air.plugin.WebSphere_98_b9f10d322ce14ba5b38aa4757ce3ac59f5ec7643b2b922935ccab03536b404a2\lib\uDeployRestClient.jar;C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\plugins\com.urbancode.air.plugin.WebSphere_98_b9f10d322ce14ba5b38aa4757ce3ac59f5ec7643b2b922935ccab03536b404a2\lib\jettison-1.1.jar" "C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\plugins\com.urbancode.air.plugin.WebSphere_98_b9f10d322ce14ba5b38aa4757ce3ac59f5ec7643b2b922935ccab03536b404a2\wasDiscovery.groovy" "C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\temp\logs8306861047267428227\input.props" "C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\temp\logs8306861047267428227\output.props""'
working directory: C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\temp
properties:
  PLUGIN_INPUT_PROPS=C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\temp\logs8306861047267428227\input.props
  PLUGIN_OUTPUT_PROPS=C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\temp\logs8306861047267428227\output.props
  pathOverride=
  profilePathAgent=
  profilePathResource=
  resourcePath=/Topology Discovery/T500
environment:
  AGENT_HOME=C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent
  AH_WEB_URL=https://localhost:8443
  AUTH_TOKEN=****
  DS_SYSTEM_ENCODING=Cp1252
  JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Dconsole.encoding=Cp1252
  PLUGIN_HOME=C:\Program Files\ibm-ucd\agent\var\plugins\com.urbancode.air.plugin.WebSphere_98_b9f10d322ce14ba5b38aa4757ce3ac59f5ec7643b2b922935ccab03536b404a2
  UD_DIALOGUE_ID=4f5c360e-69e0-4f52-87e0-6dfc6b5e01a1
================================================================================
**Checking path for WebSphere install: C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\wsadmin.bat
Checking path for WebSphere install: C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\wsadmin.bat
WebSphere installation not found. Ending discovery process.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `wsadmin.path` property on the agent resource to the location of the wsadmin file. See step 2 in the following document:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.2.2/com.ibm.udeploy.doc/topics/resources_import_was.html